# How to display an alert in ejs file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, ejs

I would like to access a document object and want to use an alert for example.

So I've created a function in the ejs file and I want to show an alert when I have an error. So I am rendering my ejs file and give 2 params, one is the result and the other one is an error. and want to show if there is an error, show an alert.

```
 res.render('appandfeature',{data: apps, error:error});
```

and my ejs file

```
<% if(error!=null) 
showAlert(error.message);

%>  

showAlert = function(err) {

  alert('error: ' + err);
}
%>
```

As can be seen, I am calling alert and I have an error that is 'alert is not defined'.

I know it is server-side stuff. The question is how can I call an alert in ejs? I do not want to do something from ajax. If I can solve this problem in ejs, it would be great.

Comment: You seem to be confusing which code runs on the server and which code runs on the client. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72975849/6243352) for a deeper explanation than what's been provided in this thread so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can access EJS variable inside script tag :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var error = <%= error %>;          

if(error!=null) 
{  
  showAlert(error.message);
}


showAlert = function(err) {
  alert('error: ' + err);
}
</script>
```