# How to run JS function in EJS template - Express, EJS and UIkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, uikit, ejs

I get `UIkit is not defined` though the JS is loaded in the header. Even `alert` doesn't work. How to solve this?

EJS index template-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit.min.css" />
    <script src="js/uikit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
    <title>Site</title>

</head>

<body>

    <% if (message) {%>
        <%= UIkit.notification(message) %>
    <% }; %>

</body>
</html>
```

Express app JS

```
var message = 'Error - not found';
//routes
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
response.render('index', {message: message});
}
```

Error

```
    17|     <% if (message) {%>

 >> 18|         <%= UIkit.notification(message) %>

    19|     <% }; %>

    20|             <div class="uk-width-1-1">


UIkit is not defined
```

Error on trying alert

```
    17|     <% if (message) {%>

 >> 18|         <%= alert('test') %>

    19|     <% }; %>
   
    20|             <div class="uk-width-1-1">


alert is not defined
```

Comment: EJS runs on the server so the JavaScript in the header isn't executed yet. EJS is a preprocessor--it generates the browser JS code using Node JS code. (technically, EJS can run in the browser on a string but that's not what's going on here)

Comment: @ggorlen `<script src="js/uikit.min.js"></script>` is included in header, gets loaded when page is rendered. And why would it do the same for `alert`?

Comment: I don't think you understand what I tried to communicate. That script tag would be executed when the page is rendered by the client, but the `UIkit.notification(message)` code is trying to run in Node, on the server, before the client even gets the HTML payload. You probably want to inject that `UIkit` call as a string so that it runs on the client rather than Node, e.g. `<%= "UIkit.notification(message)" %>`. Same for `alert`. Node has no `alert` function, that's a browser thing.

Comment: @ggorlen understood.  How to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display an alert in ejs file in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058889/how-to-display-an-alert-in-ejs-file-in-nodejs)

Comment: @ggorlen trying..

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some confusion about which code runs on the server and which code runs on the client.

In your setup, EJS is running on the Node server and building a string of HTML that's eventually sent to the client where it's executed in the client's browser. The EJS `<%= ... >` syntax lets you evaluate a JS expression in Node context on the server, not in the browser, letting you inject dynamic content into the HTML string.

Here, `<%= alert() =>` says "call Node's `alert` function on the server and inject the return value into the template". But that makes no sense--Node has no such `alert()` function, nor does it have access to anything that might have been included in a `<script>`. All of that stuff won't be available until long after EJS has finished building the HTML string and sent it to the client.

Probably what you're trying to do is inject the string that *represents* the function you want to call into the template:

```js
eval(ejs.render(`<%= "alert(42)" %>`));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ejs@3.1.6/ejs.min.js"></script>
```

Rather than the failing code:

```js
window.alert = undefined; // simulate Node, which has no alert()
console.log(ejs.render(`<%= alert(42) %>`)); // fail, trying to call undef func
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ejs@3.1.6/ejs.min.js"></script>
```

In the top example, the *string* `"alert(42)"` is injected into the template and sent to the "client", where `eval()` invokes it, roughly simulating how your script will ultimately be evaluated.

At any rate, there's probably a better way to achieve this result of conditionally setting up a function call, but getting clear on the concept is 99% of the battle.

For example, syntax like this is possible as well:

```js
const template = `
<% if (message) {%>
  alert("<%= message %>")
<% }; %>
`;

eval(ejs.render(template, {message: "hey"}));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ejs@3.1.6/ejs.min.js"></script>
```

Pop quiz: if you replace `alert("<%= message %>")` with `alert(message)` in the above code, will it work? Why or why not? Try it and see.

If you can answer this question, you probably understand the difference between evaluating something while EJS runs versus evaluating EJS' output.

<sub>*Note: `eval` is used purely for convenience/pedagogical purposes only here to simulate the client evaluating the HTML script; I'm not advocating using it in a real app!*</sub>

Comment: Still trying. give me some time. I will reply an update after sometime.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have already installed EJS with `npm install ejs`.

Make sure you have the following middleware in your express app (I always missed this middleware as a beginner):

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

As far as alert() is concerned, as others have pointed out, alert() won't work as you run it on the server. EJS gets converted to HTML via its engine before it is rendered on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using `<body onload="UIkit.notification({message:'<%=message%>'})">`